# Getting error when I try to create an iceberg table using dataFrame.write() in spark and store it in a cloud Filesystem source

Tags: scala, apache-spark, azure-databricks

Following is the script I wrote:

```
var df2 = spark.read.parquet("<file_path>")

df2.write.format("iceberg").save(<destination_path>)
```

When I ran the script I am getting the following error:

```
RuntimeException: Failed to get table info from metastore gs://dremio-qa/flatten.listofstructwithnulls30_iceberg
Caused by: MetaException: Exception thrown when executing query : SELECT DISTINCT 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.model.MTable' AS NUCLEUS_TYPE,A0.CREATE_TIME,A0.LAST_ACCESS_TIME,A0.OWNER,A0.RETENTION,A0.IS_REWRITE_ENABLED,A0.TBL_NAME,A0.TBL_TYPE,A0.TBL_ID FROM TBLS A0 LEFT OUTER JOIN DBS B0 ON A0.DB_ID = B0.DB_ID WHERE A0.TBL_NAME = ? AND B0.`NAME` = ?
Caused by: JDOException: Exception thrown when executing query : SELECT DISTINCT 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.model.MTable' AS NUCLEUS_TYPE,A0.CREATE_TIME,A0.LAST_ACCESS_TIME,A0.OWNER,A0.RETENTION,A0.IS_REWRITE_ENABLED,A0.TBL_NAME,A0.TBL_TYPE,A0.TBL_ID FROM TBLS A0 LEFT OUTER JOIN DBS B0 ON A0.DB_ID = B0.DB_ID WHERE A0.TBL_NAME = ? AND B0.`NAME` = ?
Caused by: SQLSyntaxErrorException: (conn=65340) Unknown column 'A0.IS_REWRITE_ENABLED' in 'field list'
Caused by: MariaDbSqlException: Unknown column 'A0.IS_REWRITE_ENABLED' in 'field list'
Caused by: SQLException: Unknown column 'A0.IS_REWRITE_ENABLED' in 'field list'
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

```
data.write
    .format("iceberg")
    .mode("append")
    .save("db.table")
```

You should user `db.table` instead of '<destination_path>'